# Casting dynamically C#

Tags: c#, casting

Basically I have

```
long readval;
unchecked
{
      readval = (long)mycustom.gg; 
     //gg is ulong.MaxValue, mycustom is ulong enum
}
//readval at this point is -1 as expected
Type underlying = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(mycustom)); 

//underlying is ulong or UInt64
var value = Convert.ChangeType(readvalue, underlying); //Exception cannot convert long value of -1 to ulong, out of range
mycustom returnval = (mycustom)Enum.ToObject(typeof(mycustom), value);
```

This is just a test piece of code, I only need to figure out how to cast to the underlying type from long even if the value of long is out of range. In the actual production code, enum type mycustom is a generic and readval will always be of type long. I put mycustom in this code to make it simpler to understand what I am trying to do and the problem I am having. The exception is at var value = Convert.ChangeType

Comment: which line of your code is creating the exception? sorry.... I won't be able to address your answer.

Comment: At var value = Convert.ChangeType

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using Expression Tree to perform `unchecked` convert?

```
long readval;
unchecked
{
    readval = (long)mycustom.gg;
    //gg is ulong.MaxValue, mycustom is ulong enum
}
//readval at this point is -1 as expected
Type underlying = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(mycustom));

//underlying is ulong or UInt64
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(
                Expression.Convert(
                    Expression.Constant(readval),
                    underlying)).Compile();

var value = Convert.ChangeType(lambda.DynamicInvoke(), underlying);
mycustom returnval = (mycustom)Enum.ToObject(typeof(mycustom), value);
```

You still need `Convert.ChangeType` to unbox `lambda.DynamicInvoke()` result, but it works, because it returns `underlying` type value.

And you can't generate typed lambda, because you don't know `underlying` type on compile time.

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I needed, I'm completely oblivious to lambda's so you gave me something new to learn. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to go from a ulong enum to a long and back again?

```
enum mycustom : ulong  
{
    gg = ulong.MaxValue
};


protected void ButtonServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    long readval;

    unchecked
    {
        readval = (long)mycustom.gg;
        //gg is ulong.MaxValue, mycustom is ulong enum
    }

    mycustom returnval = (mycustom) readval;
}
```